# open pdf in new tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I have a generate pdf button which open the pdf and simultaneously store the same pdf as an attachment in Case object.
But now i want is,pdf should open in new tab leave generate pdf button pafe as it is.

Can someone help me.

My vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="ZEB_RMA_ConfirmCont">

<script>  


  function newpagePDF() {
      alert('Hi11');
      var stringcase = '{!caseid }';
      var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase );
}
```

```
    <apex:form >
          <div style="height:43px; background-color:white">
             <br/>
             <h3 style="font-size: large;">
                CONFIRMATION
             </h3>
          </div>

          <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageMessage summary="Following Web Orders with RMA-{!$CurrentPage.parameters.CaseNo} were Successfully Submitted." severity="Info" strength="2"/>
              <apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!generatePdf}" />

          </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

controller :
public class ZEB_RMA_ConfirmCont {

```
 /******Variables*****/ 
 public String caseid{get;set;}
 public Case objCase{get;set;}
 Public list<attachment> listattachmnt{get;set;}
 Public Integer intattchmntsize{get;set;}

 /******Constructor***/    


   public ZEB_RMA_ConfirmCont (){

         caseid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseId');        
         objCase = new Case();
         listattachmnt = [select id from attachment where parentid = :caseid ];
         intattchmntsize = listattachmnt.size();
         intattchmntsize  = intattchmntsize + 1;

         if(caseid != null){
            objCase = [Select Id,Account.Name,Account.BillingAddress,Account.BillingStreet,Account.BillingCity,Account.BillingCountry,Account.BillingPostalCode,Account.Phone,Account.Fax,Contact.Name,Contact.Phone,Contact.Email,Contact.Fax,
                       (Select Id,Case__r.CaseNumber,Product__c,Product_Name__c,Serial_Number__c,Service_Entitlement__c From RMA_Returns__r)
                       From Case 
                       Where Id =: caseid];
         }
     }


     /******Methods*****/ 


     Public Pagereference generatePdf(){
     Pagereference pgref = new Pagereference('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+caseid );
     Blob pdfPageBlob;
     pdfPageBlob = pgref .getContentAsPDF();
     Attachment objattchd = new Attachment();

     objattchd.name = 'pdf.pdf'+'_'+caseid+ '_Attachment_no_'+intattchmntsize; 
     objattchd.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
     objattchd .Body = pdfPageBlob;
     objattchd.ParentId = caseid ;
     Insert objattchd;
     pgref.setRedirect(True);
     return pgref;
     }


}
```

Comment: I have modified my script..now trhe script runs.it also print the alert statement and value of caseid..But i am now getting a error now "window.open is not a function"can someone help.My modified script

<script>  

      
      function newpagePDF() {
          alert('Hi11');
          var stringcase = '{!caseid }';
          var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase );
    }
  
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one javascript like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newpagePDF() {
        var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+{!caseid}');
    }
</script>
```

Change your command line code to,

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!generatePdf}" onclick="newpagePDF()"/>
```

I think you have mentioned "`window.open`" as "`windows.open`" in onclick event of commandbutton.

You can see page loading (jquery or java script) errors  through,right click and click "`Inspect Element`".Click `Console` and verify the list of errors there for debugging.

Comment: I tried you Way sir.but stil the pdf is opening in same page.

Comment: <apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!generatePdf}" onclick="newpagepdf()" /> change command button code like this and create one script like above.

Comment: Code which you have posted don't have onclick script .@Ankita Singh

Comment: I wrote the same thing ..still it doesnot work

<apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!generatePdf}" onclick="newpagepdf()" />

Comment: Have the include this script too,<script>
    function newpagePDF() {
        var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+{!caseid}');
    }
</script>

Comment: Yes.I have included the script too

Comment: Is there  any error in console log?

Comment: do i need to include some script rederence in the visual force page?

Comment: there is an error : Uncaught reference erroe : newpagepdf is not defined

Comment: Check whether you have maintained perfect case for script name(newpagePDF) in definition (in script) and usage places(command button)

Comment: The problem is ,the script is not even getting called.i removed my action and tried to work with redirect...the redirect seems to not working

Comment: name of the script "newpagePDF" is case sensititve if the case mismatches at that also it will through the ablove error.Check whether you have used correct case in both the places

Comment: yes ..both are same..there is no error in that

Comment: i got the error : i am not able to access caseid variable in script..thats why the script fail because of this syntax error

Comment: can someone help now?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a visualforce page that takes the caseid for the controller.

2) Create an  link on your page

3) place target="_blank" on your 'a' tag

the code should look like this:

```
    <a href='/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?Id='{!caseid}' target='_blank' />
```

Comment: i have done that but i need to open it on click of a command button

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderAs='PDF' in your visualforce page  as below

This will always open new window and display PDF page layout.

Comment: I cannot do that ..i have tostore that pdf as an attachment too in Case Object