# type error : window.open is not a function

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have written a script to open a page in new tab on click of a command button. Unfortunately I get the following error:

> window.open is not a function()

I have not created any variable named "Open" which may have over written the open() function.

My script is like  this

```
<script>  
function newpagePDF() {
          alert('Hi11');
          var stringcase = '{!caseid }';
          var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase );
    }

</script>
```

My command buton is :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf"   onclick="newpagePDF();"/>
```

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: I am using google chroome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following statements:

```
window.open(('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase), window.name, "height=600,width=700");
```

or

```
window.open(('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase), '_blank', "height=600,width=700");
```

Comment: Sorry ..but its not working

Comment: Are you getting exception or the tab is opening in new tab? Try to copy and paste the given code and make sure `stringcase` is defined. It should work. @AnkitaSingh You have typo mistake in function.

Comment: I have defined string case.I am getting a new error now : GET https://na10.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This error has no relation with the JavaScript you wrote. I may ignore it @AnkitaSingh.

Comment: But still the window doesnot open..it renders the same page as it is

Comment: Try it `window.open(('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase), '_blank', "height=600,width=700");` @AnkitaSingh

Comment: Its working now..can you please let me know what was the error

Comment: You wrote `window.Open` instead of `window.open`. `stringcase` was not defined. New window size was not defined. @AnkitaSingh

Answer (score 2):

The reason actually is pretty simple: Unlike apex, javascript is case-sensitive. So instead of using window.Open, use window.open will resolve your issue

Comment: i am already using window.open in my code..still it doesnot work

Comment: @AnkitaSingh what is the error then? Shouldn't be Open is not a function though

Comment: Error is : GET https://na10.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @AnkitaSingh , this is the error in your visualforce page. Though you have defined your string and the caseId is correct, when it passes to VF page and try to get the resource, it failed to get the logo. I guess this is a very separate question. If you still need guidance on that, I would suggest you paste your VF code in.

Comment: Kindly refer to [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80771/open-pdf-in-new-tab/80777#80777) for code

Answer (score 0):

Change the window.open as below,

```
var newpage = window.Open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?CaseId='+stringcase ,'_blank');
```

> _blank - opens page in new tab

Try this.It will work..

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: whether it is opening in same page? Do you have code that page*(ZEB_RMA_Pdf)?

Comment: it is opening in same page.

i didnt get your second question..sorry?

Comment: I tried opening a different page..that also does not work..that also gives me the same error

Comment: Sorry my question had typo.Do you have a page like ZEB_RMA_Pdf?.Also change that Open to open in script

Comment: Yes I have a page like that

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code on the vf page

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!----}" reRender="" onclick="window.open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?id={!Case.Id}');" />
```

in the place of action u write the mehthod name whom u want to open in the new page

Comment: <apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" action="{!----}" reRender="" onclick="window.open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?id={!Case.Id}');" />

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code on the vf page :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Pdf" 
                        action="{!----}" 
                        reRender="" 
                        onclick="window.open('/apex/ZEB_RMA_Pdf?id={!Case.Id}');"     
    />
```

Comment: Ummm, What code?